# Passing a cart contents from one website to another, platform independent solution?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, e-commerce, integration, shopping-cart

I work for a product manufacturer and we do not sell products directly to customers, distribution is through our dealer network. I'd like to provide our website visitors with a means to build a shopping cart and then pass the cart contents off to the dealer website of their choice.

The solution needs to be platform independent, even though I will be developing in ASP.net since our dealers' website platforms vary. I would assume most, if not all, do not have an existing API to interface with.

What do you think would be a good means of accomplishing this task?

Thanks!

Comment: What's the problem? Either define a web service that your dealers have to implement, or at least an XML file format. Send them an XML file.

Comment: John, thanks for the suggestion but it would be best to implement something that does most/all of the work from our end. Our dealers are not particularly tech savvy. It's important that it be something that all dealers can easily take advantage of.

Comment: I'm assuming you're trying to integrate with actual webshops, rather than just sending an order? The problem with you doing all implementation is that you'll have to build a solution for each dealer, and then maintain it if they change their site etc. That's nice and friendly of you, but not necessarily very practical. It would be far better to do as John Saunders says and get them to implement a very basic webservice that could receive a simple list of product IDs/quantities etc and build a cart on their side.

Answer (score 0):

make a quote registry (with mongodb, memcached or whatever you like) and make a restful api to access that registry you can use any format you like (like json, xml ). You can even use some kind of queue manager to acomplish that